# Дефис борется с запятой

Tags: орфография, раздельно-дефис

Как правильно?

`Кривлённая вправо-влево-вниз антенка.`

`Кривлённая вправо, влево, вниз антенка.`

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Кривлённая — **вправо, влево, вниз** —  антенка.*

(1) Вставная конструкция, на  месте вставки не было знаков.

(2) Нет в словаре слова: ***вправо-влево-вниз***.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Предложение **назывное**. Для интонационного анализа нужен контекст, например:

*Домик был заброшенный. Давно не крашенная крЫша, кривлённая //— **вправо, влево, вниз** — // антЕнка.*

В этом предложении использована вставная конструкция. Интонация **вставочная**: две паузы, общий пониженный тон. В конце предложения понижение тона (на слове *антЕнка*).

Comment: Если это вставка, она не относится к частям предложения, – следовательно, надо писать *кривлёная*.

Comment: Сэр, это вводные слова не относятся, а вставные конструкции входят в состав предложения.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать дефисное написание, применяемое и в зафиксированном в словарях термине [***вправо-влево***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE):

***Кривлённая вправо-влево-вниз антенка.***

Comment: Вы уверены?  Два слова можно соединить дефисом, а три слова? Все слова с дефисным написанием должны быть в словаре, или нет?  Ведь можно тогда  и четвертое написать.

Comment: @Sharon, напомню Вам Ваши же слова, сказанные в одной из недавних тем: «_Я уверена, что вам понравится метод интонационного анализа. Он совсем несложный, просто опыт нужен_». Примените этот опыт к разбираемому предложению.

Comment: Вы все-таки пишете мою биографию) Чуть позже применю, сейчас времени нет. А вы найдите ссылку на дефисное написание трех слов, пжста.

Comment: А по поводу наличия трёхдефисного написания в словарях… Не думаю, что кто-либо в каком-либо из словарей найдёт слово _**Санкт-Петербург-Сортировочный-Московский**_. Даже Вы, Sharon! Но справочное бюро Грамоты.ру его использует: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=Три%20дефиса

Comment: Или это: «_**Три компонента слова могут быть соединены двумя дефисами: инди-поп-группа**_». http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=273121

Comment: У нас другое: сложные наречия, полученные соединением антонимов, синонимов и т.д.  Что-нибудь из темы правописания наречий. Я только точь-в-точь знаю. Please.

Answer (score 1):

> **4.** Пишутся через дефис наречия, образованные повторением того же самого слова или той же основы, а также сочетанием двух синонимических или связанных по ассоциации слов, например: ***едва-едва, чуть-чуть, как-никак, крест-накрест, туго-натуго, мало-помалу, нежданно-негаданно, не сегодня-завтра, подобру-поздорову, с бухты-барахты, тихо-мирно, худо-бедно.***

Смотрим на нашу антенку. Она стационарна: вверх-вниз не изгибается, вправо-влево не наклоняется — то есть **туда-сюда** не шатается. Она искривлена сначала вправо, потом влево, затем вниз.
Ну... Так и запишем (без борьбы):
*Кривлённая **вправо, влево и вниз** антенка.*

А для чего-то, что находится в непонятном, хаотическом или неконтролируемом движении, мне кажется, **можно** использовать сложные наречия.
Вот подходящий пример ([Г. Давыдов. Вечное перо](http://www.nm1925.ru/Archive/Journal6_2008_9/Content/Publication6_2264/Default.aspx)), мне нравится:

> Шведская горка, или, еще проще, шведский шкаф, — это будто бы просто поставленные одна на другую полки, передняя стенка которых, как у полок в наши дни, стеклянная. Правда, она охвачена деревянной рамой и потому схожа с оконцем. Этого мало. Главная причуда шведской горки в том, каким способом открывается оконце. Если вас некому было посвятить в их тайну, ждите неприятностей. Либо вы попросту не откроете, либо оконце (после вихляний **вверх-вниз-вбок**, снова вверх-вниз-вбок) останется у вас в руках.

[§ 57. Дефисное написание наречий](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL02/81920140.html#id-14%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-toc)

Comment: Но в грамм. книгах нет ни одного сказания про наречия, состоящие из трёх или более слов, к сожалению.

Comment: Ну... В таком случае, Леопольд, будем считать это авторским изобретением, неологизмом. Смысл же в том, что для вашего описания это не подходит.

Comment: Почему-с, Римма?

Comment: Некорректная грамматика: Кривлённая вправо, влево и вниз антенка. Однородный ряд в позиции одного слова (обстоятельства). Сравнить:  Кривленная вбок антенка.